# Return Max Correlation and Row Name From Corr Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I am trying to find the maximum correlation in each column of a `data.frame` object by using the `cor` function.  Let's say this object looks like

```
A <- rnorm(100,5,1)
B <- rnorm(100,6,1)
C <- rnorm(100,7,4)
D <- rnorm(100,4,2)
E <- rnorm(100,4,3)


M <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
N <- cor(M)
```

And the correlation matrix looks like

```
>N

             A           B            C            D            E
A  1.000000000  0.02676645  0.000462529  0.026875495 -0.054506842
B  0.026766455  1.00000000 -0.150622473  0.037911600 -0.071794930
C  0.000462529 -0.15062247  1.000000000  0.015170017  0.026090225
D  0.026875495  0.03791160  0.015170017  1.000000000 -0.001968634
E -0.054506842 -0.07179493  0.026090225 -0.001968634  1.000000000
```

In the case of the first column (A) I'd like R to return to me the value "D" since it's the maximum non-negative, non-"1" value in column A, along with it's associated correlation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(N))[Var1 != Var2, .SD[which.max(value)], keyby=Var1]
```

Result with @cory's data (using `set.seed(9)`):

```
   Var1 Var2      value
1:    A    D 0.28933634
2:    B    C 0.13483843
3:    C    B 0.13483843
4:    D    A 0.28933634
5:    E    C 0.02588474
```

To understand how it works, first try running `melt(N)`, which puts the data in long format.

Comment: The example I posted was a generalized form of a 251-feature correlation matrix I am using.  Could you give me a suggestion about how to change your `Var1 != Var2` in order to yield an output with dims == (251,3)?

Comment: @D8Amonk When you say 251 features, do you mean that M has 251 columns? If so, I guess this code should still work. You have to `install.packages('data.table')` first, though.

Comment: I do.  When I run that code I get `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Var1' not found`

Comment: @D8Amonk Did you include the `setDT()` part?

Answer (score 3):

The column numbers are

```
(n <- max.col(`diag<-`(N,0)))
# [1] 4 4 5 2 3
```

The names are

```
colnames(N)[n]
# [1] "D" "D" "E" "B" "C"
```

The values are

```
N[cbind(seq_len(nrow(N)),n)]
# [1] 0.02687549 0.03791160 0.02609023 0.03791160 0.02609023
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the `diag<-` section is doing?

Comment: Zeroing out the diagonal of the matrix. It's the same as `diag(N) <- 0` but returns a mutated copy instead of mutating the original.

Comment: You can think of it as shorthand for `N2 <- N; diag(N2) <- 0; return(N2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` on rows to get the max of the row for values less than one. Then use `which` to get the column index and then use the `colNames` to get the actual letters...

```
set.seed(9)
A <- rnorm(100,5,1)
B <- rnorm(100,6,1)
C <- rnorm(100,7,4)
D <- rnorm(100,4,2)
E <- rnorm(100,4,3)

M <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
N <- cor(M)

N
            A            B           C           D           E
A 1.000000000  0.005865532  0.03595202  0.28933634  0.00795076
B 0.005865532  1.000000000  0.13483843  0.04252079 -0.09567275
C 0.035952017  0.134838434  1.00000000 -0.01160411  0.02588474
D 0.289336335  0.042520787 -0.01160411  1.00000000 -0.12054680
E 0.007950760 -0.095672747  0.02588474 -0.12054680  1.00000000

colnames(N)[apply(N, 1, function (x) which(x==max(x[x<1])))]
[1] "D" "C" "B" "A" "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

The corrr package gives a simple way to do it.

```r
library(corrr)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(9)
A <- rnorm(100, 5, 1)
B <- rnorm(100, 6, 1)
C <- rnorm(100, 7, 4)
D <- rnorm(100, 4, 2)
E <- rnorm(100, 4, 3)
M <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)
N <- corrr::correlate(M)

print(N)
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   term         A        B       C       D        E
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 A     NA        0.00587  0.0360  0.289   0.00795
# 2 B      0.00587 NA        0.135   0.0425 -0.0957
# 3 C      0.0360   0.135   NA      -0.0116  0.0259
# 4 D      0.289    0.0425  -0.0116 NA      -0.121
# 5 E      0.00795 -0.0957   0.0259 -0.121  NA

head(dplyr::arrange(corrr::stretch(N, remove.dups = TRUE), desc(r)), 3)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   x     y          r
#   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 A     D     0.289
# 2 B     C     0.135
# 3 B     D     0.0425
```